# How to access multiple elements in c++ Eigen array?

Tags: c++, eigen, matrix-indexing

I want to retrieve certain elements in an Eigen array and return them as a vector. I use the following code:

```cpp
Eigen::ArrayXXi test;
test.resize(5,5);
test.setRandom();
Eigen::Matrix<int, 2, 3> inds;
inds<<0, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1;
auto res = test(inds.row(0), inds.row(1));
std::cout<<"test: \n"<<test <<std::endl;
std::cout<<"inds: \n"<<inds <<std::endl;
std::cout<<"res: \n"<<res <<std::endl;
```

The output is:

```
  test:
  730547559  -649503489  -48539462    893772102  -1038736613
 -226810938  -353856438   276748203   291438716  -552146456
  607950953   576018668  -290373134   466641602  -779039257
  640895091  -477225175   28778235   -769652652   653214605
  884005969   115899597   971155939   229713912  -737276042

  inds:
  0 2 3
  2 3 1

  res:
 -48539462   893772102  -649503489
 -290373134  466641602   576018668
  28778235  -769652652  -477225175
```

The result is a matrix. I note that the diagonal of the matrix is the result I want. I could use `res.diagonal()` to retrieve the vector. However, I am still wondering if I can do the same thing in a more efficient way.

Answer (score 1):

You can reshape the `test` Array to a column and then use the single-index access operator:

```
auto res = test.reshaped()(inds.row(0) + test.rows() * inds.row(1));
```

Generally, be careful when using `auto` with Eigen expressions (this case is fine, as long as `test` and `inds` are still valid when `res` is used).